# Determining cause of cordova iOS build failure

Tags: ios, cordova, build

My cordova phone application is building and running well in android, and now I'd like to build for ios. I can't do this in my linux environment, so I'm using a mini-mac with the Xcode tools installed.

I cloned the git repo to a working tree, and I'm running

```
cordova build ios
```

In the build output, I'm getting the following, with "fatal error", "BUILD FAILED" and "Error: ..." in red.

```
/Users/mgfrobozz/Desktop/asap_cordova/platforms/ios/ASAP Media/Plugins/org.apache.cordova.dialogs/CDVNotification.m:21:9: fatal error: 
      'Cordova/NSDictionary+Extensions.h' file not found
```

I found https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-8659, which indicated this issue (deprecated dependency in ios) was resolved in cordova 4.0.0, but I'm running cordova 6.0.0.

I don't know enough about the cordova guts to know how to fix CDVNotification.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

Try the command: `cordova platform update ios`